# How to use $scope.$on in typescript and angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am new to typescript and I'm trying to convert this angular controller to typescript but I'm having issues with the **$scope.$on()**.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('controllers').controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$location', 'NavigationServices',
    function ($scope, $location, NavigationServices) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.isSideBarOpen = NavigationServices.getSideBarState();

        vm.toggleSideBar = function () {
            NavigationServices.toggleSideBar();
        };

        $scope.$on('navigation:sidebar', function (event, data) {
            vm.isSideBarOpen = data;
        });

    }]);
})();
```

The typescript I have try:

```
module app.controllers {

import IScope = ng.IScope;
import ILocationService = ng.ILocationService;
import INavigationServices = app.services.INavigationServices;

interface INavbarController {
    isSidebarOpen: boolean;
    toggleSideBar(): void;
}

class NavbarController implements INavbarController {
    isSidebarOpen: boolean;

    static $inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'NavigationServices'];
    constructor(private $scope: IScope, private $location: ILocationService, private NavigationServices: INavigationServices){
        var _this = this;
        _this.isSidebarOpen = this.NavigationServices.getSideBarState();

        this.$scope.$on('navigation:sidebar', (event: ng.IAngularEvent, data: boolean) => {
            _this.isSidebarOpen = data;
        });
    }

    toggleSideBar(): void {
        this.NavigationServices.toggleSideBar();
    }
}

angular.module('controllers')
    .controller('NavigationController', NavbarController);
}
```

I get no errors but it doesn't work. Everything worked fine without the typescript.

Here is the NavigationServices factory:

```
module app.services {
'use strict';

export interface INavigationServices {
    toggleSideBar(): void;
    getSideBarState(): boolean;
    closeSideBar(): void;
    openSideBar(): void;
}

class NavigationServices implements INavigationServices {
    private isSideBarOpen: boolean;

    constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
        this.isSideBarOpen = false;
    }

    toggleSideBar(): void {
        this.isSideBarOpen = !this.isSideBarOpen;
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('navigation:sidebar', this.isSideBarOpen);
    }

    getSideBarState(): boolean {
        return this.isSideBarOpen;
    }

    closeSideBar(): void {
        this.isSideBarOpen = false;
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('navigation:sidebar', this.isSideBarOpen);
    }

    openSideBar(): void {
        this.isSideBarOpen = true;
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('navigation:sidebar', this.isSideBarOpen);
    }
}

angular.module('services').factory('NavigationServices', ['$rootScope', ($rootScope) => new NavigationServices($rootScope)]);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not just `$scope.$on` ?

Comment: Tried $scope.$on(...) with the constructor taking a private & public $scope and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After allot more debugging i noticed that the $scope.$on was getting trigger and the _this.isSidebarOpen was getting updated. I noticed that in the js file the **vm.isSideBarOpen** contains a CAPITAL B and in typescript is lower case. Because of this the binding was broken between the view and controller. i change _this.isSidebarOpen to _this.isSideBarOpen and everything is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I edited my response. Previous answers are correct. Still need to inject $scope for watch and listen to event